# Know PHP Script CPU usage with full script path

Tags: centos, php

I want to find which PHP script on my server using more CPU power, how can i check?

Is there any command or script to check which php files (With its full location) consuming more cpu power?

Answer (score 2):

That heavily depends on the way you run PHP scripts on your server.
But in most cases you may use a PHP profiler.

[Profiling with XHProf](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/)

[Enhanced PHP performance profiling with Xhprof](http://blog.cnizz.com/2012/05/05/enhanced-php-performance-profiling-with-xhprof/)

Answer (score 1):

if you're using apache you can enable mod_status with extendestatus = on
so you can monitor per script CPU usage, see http://www.tecmint.com/monitor-apache-web-server-load-and-page-statistics/